# SQLite basic example

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to create a database with SQLite with c# then create a table insert data then close the connection. I have just downloaded System.Data.SQLite.dll lybrary and I am not sure how to use it. There are a lot of examples in the internet but all of them seem to have a database already. Or maybe I am doing something wrong.

It will be nice If I can have a short example to just create a database, table and basic query.

EDIT

I have tried the examples provided by the comments but I don't understand why I do get errors. Maybe I downloaded the wrong library? 
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Sqlite Embedded database from application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473418/creating-sqlite-embedded-database-from-application)

Comment: above link to create a database. use the search feature to find many examples of how to create/query/update tables.

Comment: SQLite works (almost) just like any other ADO (is this the general name for the `Sql*` stuff?) connector. http://sqlite.org describes the accepted language and specific quirks/limitations.

Comment: What kind of error did you get?

Comment: ArgumentException was unhandled:  Invalid ConnectionString format for parameter "FailIfMissing"

Comment: I think it is the library that I imported I will try to download a different one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error was because I was using .NET Framework 4.0 . I downgraded to 2.0 and it worked. Sorry for the question. It will be nice to use it with .NET Framework 4.0 though.

---

Edit:

It actually works with .NET Framework 4.0  I had to add this lines of code to my app.config file:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" />
</startup>
```

also if you plan to use ado.net in your solution I experience a lot of problems when deploying. Everything worked great under development. If you use ado.net and you plan on deploying your app then include also:

```
<!--Sqlite configuration so that it works with ado.net-->
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/>
    <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite"
      type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

### if you include that last part in your app.config file then you will have to make sure that:

[image]

### those dll's have to be in your output directory.

if you deploy make sure that you copy those files to the working directory

Comment: did u try my above suggestion to fix?

Answer (score 0):

shouldnt it be `{"FailIfMissing", "False"}` instead of `{"FailIfMissing=False", "False"}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Please change the Platform Target for your C# project to Project Settings > Build > Platform Target: Any CPU.

I had a similar error occurred when i tried to run in a x64 machine with SQLite x64 binaries. But worked fine after these settings were changed